# I'm trying to make a call to an API, but i'm getting errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I'm trying to make a call to Spotify API. When I run `Spotify.getSongs()`, I get an error. This is the error I get:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'items' of undefined.

However when I define `getSongs` as a function outside of this object, it works fine. How can I make the call to `Spotify.getSongs()` work?

```js
let Spotify = {
  getOAuth() {
    fetch("https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token", {
      method: "POST",
      body:
        "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=" +
        clientId +
        "&client_secret=" +
        clientSecret,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
      }
    })
      .then(function(resp) {
        // Return the response as JSON
        return resp.json();
      })
      .then(function(data) {
        // Log the API data
        console.log("token", data);

        // Store token data
        this.token = data.access_token;
        this.tokenType = data.token_type;
        this.expires = new Date().getTime() + data.expires_in * 1000;
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        // Log any errors
        console.log("something went wrong", err);
      });
  },

  getSongs() {
    return fetch(
      `https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=inception%20soundtrack&type=playlist`,
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: this.tokenType + " " + this.token,
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
      }
    )
      .then(resp => resp.json())
      .then(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        let tracks = data.playlists.items[0].href;

        return fetch(
          `${tracks}/tracks?fields=items(track(name,artists(name),album(name,href)))`,
          {
            headers: {
              Authorization: this.tokenType + " " + this.token,
              "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
          }
        );
      })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        return data.items.map(info => ({
          name: info.track.name,
          artist: info.track.artists[0].name,
          album: info.track.album.name
        }));
      });
  }

  // If current token is invalid, get a new one
  // makeCall() {
  //   if (!this.expires || this.expires - new Date().getTime() < 1) {
  //     console.log("new call");
  //     this.getOAuth().then(function() {
  //       this.getSongs();
  //     });
  //   }
  // }
};
```

Comment: Did you check if the header's you're sending are correct. Check for tokenType and token values. Add a debugger/console.log there. Clearly the API isn't returning anything and hence the error. Also, always check for existence of an object before trying to access its property.

Comment: When I call Spotify.getOAuth() for example it works fine. When I define getSongs() as a function outside of the object it works fine. I don't understand why it won't work inside of the object

Comment: Maybe you call `getSongs` before `getOAuth` finished?

Comment: Also, you have `console.log` statements here - what do they output? Please include all the debugging details in your question. Also please add the stack of the error and point out what line in your code it refers to.

Comment: I don't see you returning the `fetch` call's result in `getOAuth`. So you _can't_ even wait for its completion (because you can't call `then` on it)!

Comment: I called Spotify.getOAuth() first, which works fine, but then when I call Spotify.getSongs(). I get 400 error. This is the error I get    ```VM61:34 GET https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=inception%20soundtrack&type=playlist 400
getSongs @ VM61:34
(anonymous) @ VM165:1
VM61:45 {error: {…}}
VM61:46 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'items' of undefined
    at <anonymous>:46:37```